# variable name contains a variable inside it

Tags: variable, echo, for

I am trying to echo some values using a `for` loop.

`hwEventType.txt` contains this :

```
11000
11002
11004
11006
13025
13026
```

Code :

```
for event in $(cat /path/hwEventType.txt)
do
eval miny_"$event"_2001=`cut -f4 -d"|" /path/G_2001_DCC_ErrorCode_STAT_"$event"_"$filedate1".txt | sort -n | head -1`
done
```

`filedate1` is today's date

files G_2001_DCC_ErrorCode_STAT_"$event"_"$filedate1".txt
contains below information:

```
20180205 2356|2001|11000|24034
20180205 2357|2001|11000|24441
20180205 2358|2001|11000|25039
20180205 2359|2001|11000|24637
20180206 0000|2001|11000|24795
20180206 0001|2001|11000|23979
20180206 0002|2001|11000|24081
20180206 0003|2001|11000|24103
20180206 0004|2001|11000|23634
20180206 0005|2001|11000|23926
```

I want to perform the below :

```
for event in $(cat /path/hwEventType.txt); do echo "$minx_$event_2001"; done
```

But I got empty lines.

Is there any way to use a variable contains in its name a variable?

Answer (score 1):

To possible ways to achieve this:

- using a intermediate variable name :

  for event in $(cat /path/hwEventType.txt); do
    echo myvar="minx_$event_2001"; 
    echo ${!myvar}; 
  done
- use a table to store / retrieve things instead of separate variables in your loops:

  miny[$event]=$(cut -f4 - ... )

and then

```
echo ${miny[$event]}
```